# " I have to go home so I need to leave early" is it correct?

Tags: grammar, email

" I have to go home so I need to leave early" is it correct when we are asking for early leave permission in mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is all you say, it might be considered rude. It can sound like you expect or are entitled to leave early. Also, it seems vague. I would recommend that you include the reason that you need to leave, if possible. I understand that the reason might be a private/personal reason, but the person from whom you request permission might require some proof.

You might consider

1. I have to go home so I need to leave early. Is this (that) ok?
2. I need to go home because (reason). Is this fine?
3. (Reason), so I need to go home early? Is that ok?
4. (Reason). May I leave early (on date you need to leave early)?

Comment: No problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

> I have to go home so I need to leave early

Grammatically it's fine although I'd add a comma after home.

However, on it's own it may not be enough. In most work environments you would be expected (and it's more polite) to provide more information - Why do you have to go home? What do you mean by early?

Consider something like the following:

> A plumber is coming to fix my shower at home, so I need to leave by 2pm

It depends a lot on the culture where you are making the request